# trouble with tkinter (python may not be configured for TK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, nlp

I'm trying to use tkinter to create a GUI for a chatbot, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kylehammerberg/PycharmProjects/chatbot/chatgui.py", line 65, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've tried a handful of different strategies to resolve this, but haven't had much luck. I know tkinter is supposed to come already installed and it should be imported as tkinter (Rather than Tkinter) when using python 3. I tried installing the future package, restarting pycharm, and then trying again. That didn't work. I'm at a loss here. Any help would be awesome. I'm using a python 3.7 interpreter if that helps.

Here's what I believe to be the relevant part of my code:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)
    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12 ))
        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "Bot: " + res + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
root = tk()
root.title("Hello")
root.geometry("400x500")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
#Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
#Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
#Create Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",12,'bold'), text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#32de97", activebackground="#3c9d9b",fg='#ffffff',
                    command= send )
#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
#EntryBox.bind("<Return>", send)
#Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)
root.mainloop()
```